# Let $ A \in \mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^n $ and $ \lambda \in \mathbb C $ show that $ \lambda* $ is also an Eigenvalue. Is my solution acceptable?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I solved this question:
Let $ A \in \mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^n  $ and $ \lambda \in \mathbb C $ show that $ \lambda* $ is also an Eigenvalue.

so the official solution to this was a bit complicated and I had a different one.

My Solution was very simple, I wonder if it's valid.

Since the determinant is equal to the product of the eigenvalues and the determinant is real the conjugate must also be an eigenvalue to cancel the imaginary part. Because otherwise we'd have a complex determinant in Real Space.
Would this be valid?
Thank you!

Comment: What if the eigenvalues are - $ \{ e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}},e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}},e^{\frac{5i\pi}{4}} \} $. Their product is equal to one and therefore the determinant is real. (Also, a small correction in your question $A \in \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$)

Comment: Ah, thank you for the counter examples I see now.

Comment: Use `$\times$` for $\times$.

Comment: I'm curious what the official solution looks like (since you say it is complicated).  I know a one-lined proof: $$Av=\lambda v\implies A\bar{v}=\bar{A}\bar{v}=\overline{Av}=\overline{\lambda v}=\bar{\lambda}\bar{v}.$$  (Here $\overline{(\_)}$ is the complex conjugate operator.)

Comment: @WETutorialSchool Hi, sorry for the late reply. I think it's basically your solution, but it shows the characteristic polynomial of the first and of the conjugation and instead of A it uses some weird greek letter that looks like an X and subscript A with (lambda) inside. I am not sure how to copy this into latex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not valid. If the determinant is $0$, then the eigenvalues could be, for instance, $0$, $1$, and $i$.

And even if the determinant is not $0$, your argument doesn't work. What prevents the eigenvalues from being $1+i$ (twice) and $2i$ (once)?

Comment: Thank you! I see now, I think you meant -2i (once) ?

Comment: No. I wrote what I meant (although $-2i$ would work too).

Comment: hmm, thanks, I'll have to ponder a bit to figure it out.